# How to render durations on my audio Playlist

Tags: reactjs, audio, duration

This is the code that gets the duration of each audio.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const currentData = data?.map(data => {
            const audio = document.createElement('audio')
            audio.src = data.assets[0].audio
       audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
                const duration = audio.duration
                setFeaturesDuration([duration])   
                console.log(duration)
                // durationArray.push(duration)
             
            })
    })
    }, [])
```

This is what i got when i console.log duration

```
PlayList.js:59 56.816333
PlayList.js:59 42.658
PlayList.js:59 50.651333
PlayList.js:59 55.928167
PlayList.js:59 57.391
PlayList.js:59 37.955833
PlayList.js:59 64.052167
PlayList.js:59 47.986833
PlayList.js:59 59.4285
PlayList.js:59 46.706833
PlayList.js:59 56.581167
```

But what i want to do is that i want to render it on my playlist, here is the code that displays my playlist, towards the end of the code contains a span that has the duration value.

```
     {data?.map((data, index) => {
                 
                // const songDuration =  getDuration(data.assets[0].audio)
                // console.log(songDuration)
                 return(
                  <li 
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    setActive(true)
                      store.addSong(data.assets[0].audio)
                      store.addImage(data.photo)
                      store.addName(data.name)
                      store.addSongIndex(index)
                  }}
                  key={data?.id}>
                  <div className="plItem">
                     <span className="trackNumber">{index + 1}</span> 
                     <span className="trackTitle">
                        <WordLimit limit={15}>
                         {data ? data.name : "word"}
                         </WordLimit> 
                      </span> 
                      <span>{Duration}</span>
                   </div>
                   </li>
                 )
             } 
              )}
```

Comment: You can't give directly, API should return the duration value. The Client-side is not the right place to get duration.

Comment: Oh, so there's no way I could get it from the client??

Comment: I don't think so, Sever should be the right place for that, When they are storing video URLs they should store duration as well. Assume you have 100 URLs in the list every renders you have to calculate the duration and show. It'll reduce performance.

Comment: Oh, alright, thanks a lot for your response..

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your response, it means a lot..

Comment: I have added an answer as well so that others can refer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so It's possible, Even if it's possible.

I would suggest sever should be the right place for that, When they are storing video URLs they should store duration as well. So that they can send all related(meta) information(title, duration, URL, etc..) in API. On the server, the calculation will be one time.

Assume you have 100 or more video URLs in the list **on every render of component, you have to calculate the duration and show**. That's not the right way of doing this It'll have a huge performance impact.